# Structure references to elements in loops in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

Imagine I have an input field and a button and when I click the button, I want an overlay to appear. Easy. (this code is meant to illustrate the situation and may not compile)

```
<MudOverlay Visible="isThinking" DarkBackground="true">
    <MudProgressCircular Indeterminate="true" />
</MudOverlay>
<MudTextField></MudTextField>
<MudButton OnClick="SaveItem">Start</MudButton>
```

(inside the "SaveItem" function I will set "isThinking" to "true")

Now imagine the same thing inside a loop of items.

```
@foreach (var item in items)
{
    <MudOverlay Visible="isThinking" DarkBackground="true">
        <MudProgressCircular Indeterminate="true" />
    </MudOverlay>
    <MudTextField @bind-Value="item.Text"></MudTextField>
    <MudButton OnClick="@(async () => await SaveItem(item))">Start</MudButton>
}
```

My question is how should I identify the correct "MudOverlay" when the button is clicked? I cannot just use `isThinking` because it would activate the MudOverlay on every item.

My best idea so far is to put a `Dictionary<string, bool> isThinkingList` where I keep the
`isThinking` status for each loop and then I use `Visible="@(isThinkingList[item.Id])"`

I highly doubt the Dictionary approach is the established best practice, hence this question. Hoping for your help. Thank you.

Comment: `OnClick="@(SaveItem(item))"` won't work. Make it a bit more real.

Comment: OK, I changed it to `@(async () => await SaveItem(item))` - I think that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to have `item.IsThinking`.

When `item` is a ViewModel then there is no problem. Otherwise, make (it) a ViewModel.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. I am using "item" as the thing that I am sending to the backend. Would it be OK to send a ViewModel to the backend to save it? Or should I then copy the values over to a different item just before calling the backend?

Comment: IsThinking sounds very much UI related, meaningless for backend and API. So yes, make a separate ViewModel layer. Map to/from the DTOs with for instance AutoMapper.